# Why no water comes out of the water line in wall for the refrigerator when I turn the valve on?

Tags: water, refrigerator, valve, shutoff

There is a water line that with a shut off valve where the refrigerator goes. I opened the valve and no water comes out. Is there another shutoff valve somewhere or could this valve be broken or clogged. How can I troubleshoot to fix this?

Comment: Trace the line, see if it is kinked somewhere, make sure valves are open....

Comment: Most of us have never been in your house, so we have no idea whether or not there's another shutoff valve for your refrigerator water line somewhere. It's most certainly *possible* that there's another one, but only you would be able to determine if that's the case.

Comment: My refrigerator supply line connects to the main water supply at the kitchen sink, and the shutoff valve is located there - there's not another one at the other end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

If the main water for the house is on (do your sinks have water?), the refrigerator hose should have water. I’d confirm it’s connected properly to your main water line. Does it come up from a basement or something? Wonder if maybe a previous owner or something cut it or didn’t connect it.